# Understand stack layout where local variables are located

Tags: gdb, stack

I have the following code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char *MASTER_PASSWORD = "password";

bool login(char * password){
  bool is_logged_in=false;
  char buf[8];
  strcpy(buf,password);
  if(strcmp(buf, MASTER_PASSWORD)==0){
     is_logged_in=true;
  }
  return is_logged_in;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  if(argc <2)    
  {
    printf("Syntax: %s <input string>\n", argv[0]);
    exit (0);
  }

  if(login(argv[1]))
    printf("you are authorized");

  return 0;
}
```

I'm using gdb to debug it, I need to know where the value of `is_logged_in` is saved in the stack. How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unless you take the address of a local variable (`&is_logged_in`), optimizing compilers mostly won't store them on the stack. You can see this by using **info scope** in gdb:

```
$ gcc -Os -g3 stack-layout.c -o stack-layout
$ gdb -q stack-layout
(gdb) info scope login
```

would show:

```
Scope for login:
<...>
Symbol is_logged_in is multi-location:
  Range 0x40064c-0x40066e: the constant 0
  Range 0x40066e-0x400673: a complex DWARF expression:
     0: DW_OP_breg0 0 [$rax]
     2: DW_OP_const1u 32
     4: DW_OP_shl
     5: DW_OP_lit0
     6: DW_OP_eq
     7: DW_OP_stack_value

, length 1.
<...>
```

Bear with me here even if you're not familiar with x86-64 assembly. Disassembling **login()** gives:

```
8   bool login(char * password){
   0x000000000040064c <+0>:     sub    $0x18,%rsp
   0x0000000000400650 <+4>:     mov    %rdi,%rsi

9     bool is_logged_in=false;
10    char buf[8];
11    strcpy(buf,password);
   0x0000000000400653 <+7>:     lea    0x8(%rsp),%rdi
   0x0000000000400658 <+12>:    callq  0x4004c0 <strcpy@plt>

12    if(strcmp(buf, MASTER_PASSWORD)==0){
   0x000000000040065d <+17>:    mov    0x2009ec(%rip),%rsi        # 0x601050 <MASTER_PASSWORD>
   0x0000000000400664 <+24>:    lea    0x8(%rsp),%rdi
   0x0000000000400669 <+29>:    callq  0x4004f0 <strcmp@plt>
   0x000000000040066e <+34>:    test   %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000400670 <+36>:    sete   %al

13       is_logged_in=true;
14    }
15  
16    return is_logged_in;
17  }
   0x0000000000400673 <+39>:    add    $0x18,%rsp
   0x0000000000400677 <+43>:    retq
```

What `gdb info scope` is saying about **is_logged_in**:

- Between **0x40064c** and **0x40066e**, i.e. between the start of the function and the call to **strcmp()**, **is_logged_in** has the constant value 0.
- Between **0x40066e** and **0x400673**, i.e. after the call to **strcmp()** till the end of the function, the value of **is_logged_in** can be calculated by:

  - Reading the 64 bit register that stores the return value from **strcmp()** (**RAX**)
  - Left shift 32 bits
  - Compare the result to 0. The value of **is_logged_in** is 1 if the equality comparison is true and 0 otherwise.

At this point some may argue that **is_logged_in** would be allocated differently if we compile with a lower optimization level, but my point is that local variables are only *guaranteed* to be on the stack if you take their address and do something with that address that the compiler would not optimize away. In this case, if you want to change the value of **is_logged_in** you're better off changing the value returned by **strcmp()** i.e. change **RAX** right after **strcmp()** returns.

If **is_logged_in** is allocated on the stack, **p &is_logged_in** would print its address in GDB. If it's not on the stack you'd get an error like

```
(gdb) p &is_logged_in
Can't take address of "is_logged_in" which isn't an lvalue.
```

The DWARF debug info format including its stack machine operations are documented at [dwarfstd.org](http://dwarfstd.org/).